# .NET Rx - ReplaySubject buffer size not working

Tags: system.reactive

I've been using .NET Reactive Extensions to observe log events as they come in. I'm currently using a class that derives from IObservable and uses a ReplaySubject to store the logs, that way I can filter and replay the logs (for example: Show me all the Error logs, or show me all the Verbose logs) without losing the logs I've buffered.

The problem is, even though I've set a buffer size on the subject:

```
this.subject = new ReplaySubject<LogEvent>(10);
```

The memory usage of my program goes through the roof when I use OnNext to add to the observable collection on an infinite loop:

```
internal void WatchForNewEvents()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                        // TODO: Add parameters for getting specific log events

                        if (this.logEventRepository.GetManyHasNewResults(parameters))
                        {
                            foreach (var recentEvent in this.logEventRepository.GetMany(parameters))
                            {
                                this.subject.OnNext(recentEvent);
                            }
                        }

                        // Commented this out for now to really see the memory go up 
                        // Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                    }
                });
        }
```

Does the buffer size on ReplaySubject not work? It doesn't seem to be clearing the buffer when  the buffer size is reached. Any help much appreciated!

UPDATE:

I add subscribers like this (Is this wrong?):

```
public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<LogEvent> observer)
        {
            return this.subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }
```

...which is called like:

```
// Inserts into UI ListView
    this.logEventObservable.Subscribe(evt => this.InsertNewLogEvent(evt));
```

Comment: What happens if you add a subscriber to the ReplaySubject? I think it shouldn't leak like this, but I'm still curious to see what happens

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I've added more info about how I add subscribers.

Comment: I have isolated the problem, although I don't know the solution yet. Subscribing to the subject BEFORE calling OnNext in a loop prevents the memory leak. Subscribing AFTER causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the definitive answer, but I suspect that you're hitting an issue because of concurrency around the scheduler you're using. The constructor you're calling on `ReplaySubject` looks like this:

```
public ReplaySubject(int bufferSize)
    : this(bufferSize, TimeSpan.MaxValue, Scheduler.CurrentThread)
{ }
```

The `Scheduler.CurrentThread` worries me. Try changing it to `Scheduler.ThreadPool` and see if that helps.

Also, as a side note, you seem to be mixing Rx with TPL and old fashioned thread sleeping. It's usually best to avoid doing that. You could change your `WatchForNewEvents` code to look like this:

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

var newEvents =
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    where this.logEventRepository.GetManyHasNewResults(parameters)
    from recentEvent in
        this.logEventRepository.GetMany(parameters).ToObservable()
    select recentEvent;

newEvents.Subscribe(this.subject);
```

That's a nice compact Rx-y way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, although changing the Scheduler didn't have an effect. I wonder if my implementation of IObservable is incorrect?

Comment: @NickRamirez - I'm sorry my hunch didn't work out. I would recommend not trying to implement `IObservable` - this is often more complicated that it appears and it is so easy to get it wrong. Use the built-in operators instead.

Comment: In the end, doing as you suggested, using Observable.Interval instead of TPL fixed the memory leak. Thanks!